# R: Filtering rows based on a group criterion

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with over 100,000 rows and with about 40 columns. The schools column has about 100 distinct schools. I have data from 1980 to 2023.
I want to keep all data from schools that have at least 10 rows for each of the years 2018 through 2022. Schools that do not meet that criterion should have all rows deleted.
In my minimal example, Schools, I have three schools.
Computing a table makes it apparent that only Washington should be retained. Adams only has 5 rows for 2018 and Jefferson has 0 for 2018.
Schools2 is what the result should look like.
How do I use the table computation or a dplyr computation to perform the filter?

```
Schools = 
  data.frame(school = c(rep('Washington', 60),
                        rep('Adams',70),
                        rep('Jefferson', 100)), 
             year = c(rep(2016, 5), rep(2018:2022, each = 10), rep(2023, 5), 
                      rep(2017, 25), rep(2018, 5), rep(2019:2022, each = 10),
                      rep(2019:2023, each = 20)),
             stuff = rnorm(230)
             )

Schools2 = 
  data.frame(school = c(rep('Washington', 60)),
             year = c(rep(2016, 5), rep(2018:2022, each = 10), rep(2023, 5)), 
             stuff = rnorm(60)
  )

table(Schools$school, Schools$year)

Schools |> group_by(school, year) |> summarize(counts = n())
```

Comment: For a school to be included, it needs to have at least 10 entries for each of the years 2018:2022.
Washington meets that criterion as it has 10 entries in each of the years 2018:2022. So all of Washington will be in the final data frame.
Adams only has 5 rows for 2018, so all of Adams is deleted. Jefferson has 0 rows for 2018, so all of Jefferson is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep only the year from 2018 to 2022 in the data with `filter`, then add a frequency count column by school, year, and `filter` only those 'school', having all count greater than or equal to 10 and if `all` the year from the range are present

```
library(dplyr)# version >= 1.1.0
Schools %>%
   filter(all(table(year[year %in% 2018:2022]) >= 10) & 
          all(2018:2022 %in% year), .by = c("school")) %>%
   as_tibble()
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 60 × 3
   school      year   stuff
   <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 Washington  2016  0.680 
 2 Washington  2016 -1.14  
 3 Washington  2016  0.0420
 4 Washington  2016 -0.603 
 5 Washington  2016  2.05  
 6 Washington  2018 -0.810 
 7 Washington  2018  0.692 
 8 Washington  2018 -0.502 
 9 Washington  2018  0.464 
10 Washington  2018  0.397 
# … with 50 more rows
```

---

Or using `count`

```
library(magrittr)
Schools %>% 
  filter(tibble(year) %>%
        filter(year %in% 2018:2022) %>%
        count(year) %>%
       pull(n) %>% 
       is_weakly_greater_than(10) %>% 
       all, all(2018:2022 %in% year) , .by = "school")
```

Comment: This looks good and produces the correct answer, but it uses add_count(). I have used dplyr for a few years but have never seen that function. I wonder if there is a way to solve my problem only using more well-known functions.

Comment: I looked more closely at the output. It is only data in 2018:2022. Since Washington is acceptable, all Washington data needs to be returned. The Washington rows from 2016 and 2023 need to be in the final table.

Comment: @user2738483 i guess there was a confusion in the logic.  Can you check the updated solution

Comment: > res1 = Schools %>% 
+   # filter(year %in% 2018:2022) %>% 
+   filter(all(n() >= 10), .by = c("school", "year"))  %>%
+   filter(all(2018:2022 %in% year), .by = "school" ) %>%
+   as_tibble()
> table(res1$school, res1$year)
            
             2018 2019 2020 2021 2022
  Washington   10   10   10   10   10
The add_count() code gave the same results.

Comment: @user2738483 Have you used the code in the updated solution or can't you see the update for some reason `Schools %>%
   filter(all(table(year[year %in% 2018:2022]) >= 10) & 
          all(2018:2022 %in% year), .by = c("school")) %>%
   as_tibble()`

Comment: The two updates solutions solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @user2738483 I commented to your reply earlier before I tested.  Then, I realized that you want to do the filtering on the subset and keep the full rows for each 'school'

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, a friend just helped me come up with a base R solution.

```
# form 2-way table, school against year
sdTable = table(Schools$school, Schools$year)

# say want years 2018-2022 having lots of rows in school data
sdTable = sdTable[,3:7]

# which have >= 10 rows in all years 2018-2022
allGtEq = function(oneRow) all(oneRow >= 10)
whichToKeep = which(apply(sdTable,1,allGtEq))

# now whichToKeep is row numbers from the table; get the school names
whichToKeep = names(whichToKeep)

# back to school data
whichOrigRowsToKeep = which(Schools$school %in% whichToKeep)
newHousing = Schools[whichOrigRowsToKeep,]
newHousing
```